# Recursively finding the maximum value in a tuple of mixed types

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

I am writing a function that recursively finds the maximum value in a tuple that may contain more tuples or lists. Currently the code tracks result, but after each recursive call is finished, the max value for the sub-list or sub-tuple is returned.

How can I change it so that only the global max is returned? I tried appending the values to a list at the end of each recursive call, but then could not return any values at the end.

Currently returns 4, 6, 10, and 20 using the sample data, want to only return 20 at the end.
Edit: Code works, append each answer to a list "result" and return the max of "result" at the end.

```
def maxInTuple(t):
    results=[]
    maxVal =0
    _max_val(t, maxVal, results)
    return max(results)

def _max_val(t, maxVal, results):
    for c in t:
        if type(c) != int:
            _max_val(c, maxVal, results)
        elif c > result
            result =c
    results.append(ans) 
    #return ans

print ( maxInTuple(([2, 3, 4], (5, 6), [10, [4, 20]])))
```

Comment: Why does `_max_val` take a `result` parameter if you are not using it and instead overriding it?

Comment: @Professor_Joykill,  originally I set result =0 in the helper function but then each time it is reset to 0 with each recursive call. I only want it to be 0 at the very beginning, does my logic make sense?

Comment: One possibility if you wanted to use `.append()` would then to do `return(max(results))` which would return the largest value in the `results` list, which would be the largest in the whole tuple.

Comment: It is nice that you provide a code example, but please make sure it runs.

Comment: @Professor_Joykill I made append work, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did to fix the code:

```
def maxInTuple(t):
    result = 0
    result = _max_val(t, result)
    return result
def _max_val(t, highest):
    for c in t:
        if type(c) != int:
            highest = _max_val(c, highest)
        else:
            if c > highest:
                highest = c
    return highest

print(maxInTuple(([2, 3, 4], (5,6),[10,[4,20]])))
```

What I did:

Had the `maxInTuple` function return the result it got from the `_max_val` function. The second variable passed to the `_max_val` function was `0` in this case. Then in the `_max_val` function if it wasn't an `int` I set highest equal to what `_max_val` with the subset was, so for example in `[2,3,4]` it would make `highest = 4`. Otherwise if `c` was an `int` then I tested if `c > highest`, meaning that highest will only be changed when `c` is actually bigger. Then, once it has finished looping through that, it will return the highest value, in this case `20`, which will be set to `result` in the `maxInTuple()` function, then `result` is returned, which is then `printed`.